# to get float values of latitude and longitude from database

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of certain regions stored in my database and to store them in an array. I have to store the values as float types. I am getting other values by the following code:

```
NSString *walkQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT Wid,WName,SName,Latitude,Longitude from Walks,SubRegions WHERE Walks.Sid=SubRegions.Sid AND Rid = %d",[regionId integerValue] ];

        sqlite3_stmt *walkstatement = nil;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(walkNameDB,[walkQuery UTF8String], -1, &walkstatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while( sqlite3_step(walkstatement) == SQLITE_ROW )
            {
                NSNumber *WId;
                int temp1 = (int)sqlite3_column_int(walkstatement, 0);
                WId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:temp1];

                char *WNameCharacter;
                WNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(walkstatement, 1);
                NSString *WNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:WNameCharacter];

                char *SNameCharacter;
                SNameCharacter = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(walkstatement, 2);
                NSString *SNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:SNameCharacter];


                NSMutableDictionary *tempWalk = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempWalk setObject:WId forKey:@"WalkId"];
                [tempWalk setObject:WNameString forKey:@"WalkName"];
                [tempWalk setObject:SNameString forKey:@"SubRegionName"];
                [regionWalkArray addObject:tempWalk];
```

Is their any way by which I can get the two float values of latitude and longitude also like I am doing in my code?

Please suggest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 float latitude  = (float) sqlite3_column_double(walkstatement, 3);
 float longitude = (float) sqlite3_column_double(walkstatement, 4);
```

And can store in dictionary like:

```
[tempWalk setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
[tempWalk setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
```

You can retrieve it like:

```
float latitude = [[tempWalk objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
float longitude = [[tempWalk objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Thanx and what next to store it in my dictionary with their keys. Please suggest me that also...

Comment: @Ashu: I have added storing and retrieving codes, please check

Comment: I have used them and they works fine but I am getting 0.00000 in my NSLog string..:(

Comment: @Ashu: where did you put the NSLog ? and use NSLog like: `NSLog(@"%f",[[tempWalk objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue]);` also check your database value is not 0

Comment: I am putting NSLog just after the code but still I am getting the same value and I have inserted values in database correctly in float format (say 23.9876)etc..

Comment: please put it on the sqlite_step statement and check whether it reurns correct value or not

Comment: @Ashu: then the database value is incorrect or your query is having some issues.

Comment: @Ashu: please add NSLog(@"%f",(float) sqlite3_column_double(walkstatement, 3)); in the query loop and check